# Error forbidden 403 on recaptcha

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently using vb.net to program a Web Service which accesses a certain website. I did this with Google and other APIs already. There has never been a problem. However, this site is different. Trying to connect to it gives the following error : **"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden"** 
Looking through the source code I found out that it uses "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js".

Could this be a problem for me connecting to the website? And if it is, is there any way to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: IS your url correct? Shouldn't it be https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js with a period, .js not ,js??

Comment: It's correct. That's my fault. I miswrote the Url. It is "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"

Comment: 403 Forbidden typically is returned when you do not have authorization to make a request.

Comment: Please add some pseudo code to help people identify the way you are calling the service and any configuration involved (if not the actual code)